# print DIC in R2OpenBUGS

Tags: r, r2winbugs, openbugs

I'm working in "R2OpenBUGS" in R. I have some mcmc chain:

```
mcmc <- bugs(data = ... DIC=TRUE ... codaPkg=TRUE)
```

My question is how to print DIC when **codaPkg = TRUE**. If codaPkg = FaLSE, then if I just do print(mcmc), it prints the DIC value at the end.

But when "codaPkf=TRUE", it just prints something like:

```
[1] "/tmp/Rtmp3OlPh5/CODAchain1.txt" "/tmp/Rtmp3OlPh5/CODAchain2.txt"
```

So, how can I print the DIC value now?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`bugs.log(paste(substr(mcmc[1],1,nchar(mcmc[1])-14),"log.txt", sep = ""))$DIC`